# iOS: UIButton doesn't show up

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview, uibutton

I'm creating a simple button and adding it as a subview to main view. It doesn't show up though.

This is the code for setting it up:

```
UIButton* contactButton = [[UIButton alloc] init];
contactButton.titleLabel.text = @"Contact Developer";
[contactButton sizeToFit];
[self.view addSubview:contactButton];
NSLog(@"X: %f || Y: %f || Width: %f || Height: %f", contactButton.frame.origin.x, contactButton.frame.origin.y, contactButton.frame.size.width, contactButton.frame.size.height);
```

As you may have noticed, I placed a bit of debug code at the end to see the position and dimensions of the button. They are: X: 0, Y: 0, Width: 30, Height: 34

This means it should be showing up in the upper left corner but it doesn't. Whats wrong?

Comment: Do not set the title label directly. Use `setTitle:forState:` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible reason for this is that you used `titleLabel`directly. Consider using `setTitle:forState:` method instead.

To be sure, consider setting `backgroundColor`, as a debug step, to make sure it's appearing.

---

**Edit** As others suggested, try using `buttonWithType:` instead of `[[UIButton alloc] init]`. I suggest using `UIButtonTypeSystem` instead of `UIButtonTypeCustom`.

Comment: Thank you. This made the button visible, however whenever I click it, it doesn't shade out like other buttons. Whats the problem with this?

Comment: This may be related to how you ```alloc```it. Try ```buttonWithType:```as the other answers suggested, but I suggest using ```UIButtonTypeSystem``` instead of ```UIButtonTypeCustom```since you're not having any custom behaviour.

Comment: Thank you very much. That solved it. I also used `contactButton.tintColor` to change the custom blue color to a more decent one.

Answer (score 1):

You should initialise the button using the following:

```
UIButton* contactButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try constructing your button a different way:

```
UIButton* contactButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
contactButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
contactButton.titleLabel.text = @"Contact Developer";
[contactButton sizeToFit];
[self.view addSubview:contactButton];
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that the button it's not being shown?

I think you are setting the title of the button incorrectly and because of the fact that a default `UIButton` has clear background and white title, it´s not visible if your superview is white too.
Instead of setting:
`contactButton.titleLabel.text = @"Contact Developer"`
use:
`[contactButton setTitle:@"Contact Developer" forState:UIControlStateNormal]`

But you can first try to set a `backgroundColor` to the button, different that the superview, to see if it's added.

Hope it helps!
(Sorry for my english if i have a mistake)

Comment: Thanks, its pretty much what Mohannad A. Hassan suggested and it worked very well.

Comment: Yes, sorry for "duplicating", I haven't seen his answer until I post mine.